# Is $0 $ radians an acute angle?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

I know that an angle less than $\frac {\pi}{2} $ radians is called acute, but under this definition, is an angle that is $0$ radians also considered acute?

Comment: It looks like $0$ radians would be called a "perigon", according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Types_of_angles).

Comment: I want to differentiate between $2\pi $ and $0 $ radians.

Comment: I don't think there's a definite answer to this question: it's terminology and the convention may vary. Usually “acute” is used for the angles of a triangle, so $0$ is not among them. But somebody could be using also degenerate triangles and consider $0$ to be acute.

Comment: 2π radians is called a 'full angle' or 'whole angle', and 0 radians can be called a line segment.

Comment: Let's call it an "empty" angle. :-)

Comment: @JasonChen $0 $ radians can be called a line segment? You must be joking, right?

Comment: Technically, it is a line segment, but if you want it to be a certain type of angle, I don't know what it's called.

Comment: @JasonChen angles are not set of points, line segments are.

Comment: @JasonChen, an angle is a number that expresses the relative position between two rays.  A line segment is a collection of points on the plane.  They are entirely different.

Comment: According to [this](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/textbook/chapter5/angles_radians.htm), $0\ \text{rad}$ is **not** acute angle. I think that site is a legitimate source.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, you are citing a [preproduction copy](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/textbook/) of a textbook being written.  There is no reason to believe that this will not change prior to publication.

Comment: Then it could be called a ray, because since there is no angle between the two rays of an angle, they overlap an become a single ray.

Comment: @JasonChen, since zero is a number (if you don't believe this you have company, sadly, among some of those answering this question) an angle of zero degrees is still an angle.

Comment: @user132181, why do you really need to know what an angle of 0 radians is called?

Comment: @JasonChen the question arose out of sheer curiosity.

Comment: @user132181, I might have an answer for you. I edited my answer. Check out Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mathcaptain](http://www.mathcaptain.com/geometry/measuring-angles.html), which is a website maintained by the publisher Pearson (which publishes math textbooks), an angle of $0$ is called a "zero" angle, an angle of $\pi$ is called a "straight" angle, and an angle of $2\pi$ is called a "complete" angle.

Comment: The hero came and saved the day.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a rather silly recourse to authority to decide on a matter on which authority has no weight. Th eonly possiblr answer to this questions is that *it depends on the definition of the OP*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I completely agree.  However, some authority is better than no authority.

Comment: Not really: nothing is more valuable that coming to terms with the facts that definitions vary and that the question of the OP, as it is, is simply unanswerable.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez my definition seems to coincide with Vadim's (from what I've read in the comments). Also, if my question is unanswerable,  why did you try to answer it?

Comment: To make it clear, $0\ \text{rad}$ is an acute angle or not?

Answer (score -1):

No, an acute angle is an angle $\theta$ for which $0<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Any proof of this?

Comment: It is the definition of an acute angle.

Comment: I'm talking about the source that offers this definition.

Comment: I don't know of any definitive source to be honest, but there is a Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle . (see the chart under "types of angles" )

Comment: @user132181, see [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/angleacute.html): «Acute angle From Latin: acutus - "sharp, pointed"
Definition: An angle whose measure is less than 90°».

Comment: @JMCF125 this doesn't help at all.

Comment: @user132181, you asked for a source.

Comment: @JMCF125 $0º $ is less than $90º $, so your source claims $0º $ is acute, after all?

Comment: Just by common sense, we can see that such a definition is pragmatic, as it resolves the ambiguity! So why not adopt this definition? Really, this is really an axiomatic question, and it has been given a good axiomatic answer.

Comment: Not only is 0 less than 90, but the resulting shape is very sharp and pointed.

Comment: @user132181, sorry, copied the wrong part, I saw the right part on my search engine: «Acute angles are the smallest, being between (but not including) zero and 90°»

Answer (score -1):

An angle of measure 0 radians is not acute. If an angle is in degrees, it is only acute if it is between 90 and 0, exclusive. For radians, it is acute if it is between π/2 and 0, exclusive. Because the definition of an acute angle doesn't include 0, 0 radians is not acute.

Edit: Additionally, in Wikipedia, "Euclid defines a plane angle as the inclination to each other, in a plane, of two lines which meet each other, and do not lie straight with respect to each other." If the two rays point in the same direction and have a common vertex, then 0 radians isn't an angle at all.

Comment: What book offers this definition? I can say that I saw a unicorn today, doesn't mean it really happened.

Comment: The McDougal Littell Geometry textbook. (California textbook)

Answer (score -3):

Since you wrote

> I know that an angle less than $\frac {\pi}{2} $ radians is called acute

then obviously an angle of zero radians is acute, simply because $0<\frac {\pi}{2}$.

Comment: $-\pi<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I implicitly assumed there may be a second part of the definition, something like "_except_ $0$ radians."

Comment: @vadim123, well, unless the OP tells us that his definition of acute angles excludes negative angles an angle of $-\pi$ radians is also an acute because, as you acutely observe, $-\pi<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Okay, then, let me obtusely observe that $-\frac{5\pi}{4}<\frac{\pi}{2}$, yet this coincides with the obtuse angle $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: *If* we are to identify angles that differ by $2\pi$, then of course the definition mentioned by the OP simply does not make sense —because *every* angle is equal to one whose measure is less that $\pi/2$— nor the one you quoted...